# Apex class to run after 6 hours like it should run 12 pm then 6 pm then 12 am then 6 am like this what is CRON_EXP for this

Tags: apex

Apex class that should run after 6 hours like it should run 12 pm then 6 pm then 12 am then 6 am like this what is CRON_EXP  for this
thanks

Answer (score 3):

This cron expression will run at 0,6,12 and 18th hour

> 0 0 0,6,12,18 * * ?

Here on hours place we are specifying times when it should run and it is running on daily basis.

Refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

for more information

Comment: thanks will implement this

Comment: @guest `0/6` will also work for this purpose.

Comment: Hello @amit it is running only on 6 am and 6 pm not at 12 am and 12 pm

Comment: is there any other cron?